# if condition based on Reading the paramiko channel buffer

Tags: python, paramiko

I have modified the code and reposting
using paramiko,  i login as normal_user  and execute "sudo su -"   on multiple servers.
few servers normal_user  has sudo access with NOPASSWD option where password is not asked for root access.
few servers normal_user  has sudo access  and password is asked.
few servers normal_user is not in sudoers file.  But when sudo su - is given, it asks password and then
tell user is not in sudoers file

Below is my code .  it works if user is asked for  sudo password
and works even  password is not asked  , the script is not when user is not in sudoers file. it should report "normal_user is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported."
pss advise

```
import paramiko
import time
import sys
import os

User_name=raw_input('Enter User name: ')
Pass_word=raw_input('Enter the password: ')
cmd=raw_input('Enter the command: ')
def node_shell(hostname, site_user, site_passwd):
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy( paramiko.AutoAddPolicy() )

    try:
        ssh.connect(hostname, username=site_user, password=site_passwd, timeout=3)
        transport = ssh.get_transport()
        transport.set_keepalive(1)

        while True:
            try:
                channel = ssh.invoke_shell()
                channel.settimeout(60)

                channel.send('sudo su -' + '\n')
                buff = ''
                while not (buff.endswith(User_name + ': ') or buff.endswith('# ')):
                    resp = channel.recv(9999)
                    buff += resp
                time.sleep(2)
                if buff.endswith(User_name + ': '):
                    channel.send('mm' + '\n')
                    buff=''
                    while not (buff.endswith('# ') or buff.endswith('reported. ')):
                       resp = channel.recv(9999)
                       buff += resp
                    time.sleep(5)
                    if buff.endswith('reported. '):
                        resp = channel.recv(9999)
                        buff += resp
                        time.sleep(2)
                        print "User does not have sudo access"
                        sys.exit(1)
                channel.send(cmd + '\n')
                buff = ''
                while not buff.endswith('# '):
                    resp = channel.recv(9999)
                    buff += resp
                time.sleep(5)
                return buff

            except Exception as e:
                print("ERROR: s failed: %s" % (hostname, e))


    except Exception as e:
        print("%s: failed to login : %s" % (hostname, e))
        ssh.close()
    return
```

Comment: Consider using `pexpect` instead of reinventing this wheel. Note also the built-in `pxssh` module.

Comment: Anyhow, the cause of your problem is plain on its face: You're looking _only_ for `normal_user:`, and not recognizing `# ` if it's seen before `normal_user:` is. Change your code so it recognizes both strings (or, as suggested above, use `pexpect` to do that automatically) and there you are.

Comment: ...this would be a better question if you showed what went wrong when you _tried_ to fix the problem the plain/simple/obvious way, instead of showing code that doesn't try to fix the problem at all and expecting someone else to do that work for you.

Comment: Hi Experts,   I have  modified the code and reposted  the issue.

Comment: `endswith` is pretty specific -- it won't match if you have the `This issue will be reported.` and then a newline and an additional prompt following (instead of the single space with no preceding newline that the current code expects to be right after that message).

Comment: Thanks  a Lot @CharlesDuffy.    you are right.
The output  ends with   "$ "   and i was  looking for  "reported."